# Animation of sun according to prayer timings in Muslim Pro ios App

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

Muslim Pro is an ios app which animates the sun position according to salah timing.I know, how to animate UIImage array to animate series of images but it doesn't give the effect which Muslim Pro ios app does. Do I need to use any animation library or it can be achieved by iOS built in framework.

Comment: hey, give a link or gif of animation

Comment: I see Muslim Pro, if you speak about that animation which happens at the sсroll (the background behind a mosque changes), its simply the picture with a transparent background is used (mosque) and second  picture with a background which changes with an alpha (it is possible to create if to make 2 imageview and with animation to change at them an alpha)

Comment: @JoeHallenbeck Thanks. I m talking about the animation, when one clicks on the prayers icon from home screen, it opens the prayer timings screen. On top of that screen the "Animation of Sun" is available. How can I achieve that?

Comment: ok i understand, now I will try to realize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/18018275/4912496

**UPDATE for fill animation**
that I could think up and realize the only thing quickly, it to create View, and is animated it to fill at the left on the right, the decision not the best, perhaps you will think up the best

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

_acrfillview.clipsToBounds = YES;
CAShapeLayer *shape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(_acrfillview.bounds.size.width / 2, _acrfillview.bounds.size.height ) radius:(_acrfillview.bounds.size.height) startAngle:0 endAngle:(M_PI) clockwise:false];
shape.path = path.CGPath;
_acrfillview.layer.mask = shape;

}

- (IBAction)startAnimation:(id)sender
{
CGPoint arcStart = CGPointMake(_sunView.center.x , _sunView.center.y);
CGPoint arcCenter = CGPointMake(0.5 * self.view.bounds.size.width, 0.5 * self.view.bounds.size.height);
CGFloat arcRadius = self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - (_sunView.frame.origin.x + _sunView.frame.size.width/2);

CGMutablePathRef arcPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(arcPath, NULL, arcStart.x, arcStart.y);
CGPathAddArc(arcPath, NULL, arcCenter.x, arcCenter.y, arcRadius, M_PI, 0, NO);

BOOL showArc = YES;
UIView* drawArcView = nil;
if (showArc)
{
    drawArcView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds];
    CAShapeLayer* showArcLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    showArcLayer.frame = drawArcView.layer.bounds;
    drawArcView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    showArcLayer.path = arcPath;
    showArcLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    showArcLayer.fillColor = nil;
    showArcLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
    showArcLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
    [drawArcView.layer addSublayer: showArcLayer];
    [self.view insertSubview: drawArcView belowSubview: _sunView];

    CAShapeLayer* animateArcLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
    animateArcLayer.frame = CGRectMake(drawArcView.layer.frame.origin.x, drawArcView.layer.frame.origin.y, 1, 1);
    animateArcLayer.path = arcPath;
    animateArcLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    animateArcLayer.strokeColor = nil;
    animateArcLayer.fillColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
    animateArcLayer.lineWidth = 0.0;
    [_acrfillview.layer addSublayer:animateArcLayer];

    CGPathRef leftStartingRectPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectMake(0,0, 0, arcRadius), 0);
    CGPathRef fullViewRectPath = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRectMake(0,0, 275, arcRadius), 0);
    CABasicAnimation *leftToRightAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    leftToRightAnimation.duration = 5.;
    leftToRightAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    leftToRightAnimation.fromValue = (__bridge id)leftStartingRectPath;
    leftToRightAnimation.toValue = (__bridge id)fullViewRectPath;
    leftToRightAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    leftToRightAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [animateArcLayer addAnimation:leftToRightAnimation forKey:@"animatePath"];

}
// The animation
CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
pathAnimation.duration = 5.0;
pathAnimation.path = arcPath;
CGPathRelease(arcPath);

[CATransaction begin];
[_sunView.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"arc"];
[CATransaction commit];
}
```

[image]

Comment: one thing more how can i fill the color in that area which is under the arc? Do I need to draw straight line with the arc path ?

Comment: @iOS_Learner yes of course, you can take x position of image view as a basis, and synchronize it with expansion of the simple UIView, it should works like UIProgressView

Comment: @iOS_Learner if U need help with it...Write here.

Comment: ok , Let my try first, if i got stuck then definitely will seek help. Thanks

Comment: @iOS_Learner, I will be glad to help and what about achieve my answer?))

Comment: I am developing an iOS app for my client in which he wants this functionality.

Comment: If you have seen the muslim pro app then you can get the idea how exactly i want to fill the color  that is between stright line and arc. I mean white area under the arc.

Comment: @iOS_Learner give me 15-20 min

Comment: Err, shouldn't you reveal that you didn't write this code at all and that you got it from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18018275/299924) without attribution?

Comment: @trojanfoe , yes of course, I inserted the link, but if look more attentively, there on by that code is still which was written already by me....

Comment: If you based your solution on someone's else work then it's common courtesy to attribute them instead of pretending the work is all yours.

Comment: @trojanfoe, hey friend, about what you speak? the part of the answer is taken! me asked to help with realization of animation and I took part of realization from other answer. You want that I removed the answer?

Comment: Not at all, simply that you attribute the work of others, which you have now done.